# Calling a variable value from another script's class's functions

Tags: python, function, class, variables

I need help! I was trying to mod a game BombSquad and was trying to build a banning system for my server.

okay so there is a funtion that denies people to enter

```
def onPlayerRequest(self, player):
    """
    Called when a new bs.Player wants to join;
    should return True or False to accept/reject.
    """
    # limit player counts based on pro purchase/etc *unless* we're in a stress test
    if bsUtils._gStressTestResetTimer is None:
        if len(self.players) >= self._maxPlayers:
            # print a rejection message *only* to the client trying to joinz
            # (prevents spamming everyone else in the game)
                bs.playSound(bs.getSound('error'))
                bs.screenMessage(bs.Lstr(resource='playerLimitReachedText', subs=[('${COUNT}', bsInternal._getAccountDisplayString())]),
                            color=(0.8, 0.0, 0.0),
                            clients=[player.getInputDevice().getClientID()],
                            transient=True)
                return False
    bs.playSound(bs.getSound('dripity'))
    return True
```

I need the player name from another file, and I will put it in the if statement to check if it matches the banlist and done!
The files that brings out the player name is

```
class DamnPartyWindow(PartyWindow):

def _onPartyMemberPress(self, clientID, isHost, widget):
    # if we're the host, pop up 'kick' options for all non-host members
    if bsInternal._getForegroundHostSession() is not None:
        kickStr = bs.Lstr(resource='kickText')

    else:
        # kick-votes appeared in build 14248
            if bsInternal._getConnectionToHostInfo().get('buildNumber', 0) < 14248:
                return
    kickStr = bs.Lstr(resource='kickVoteText')
    for rst in self._roster:
            cid = rst['clientID']
            if cid == clientID:
                bs.screenMessage(rst['displayString'])
                break
    p = PopupMenuWindow(position=widget.getScreenSpaceCenter(),
                scale=2.3 if gSmallUI else 1.65 if gMedUI else 1.23,
                choices=['kick'],
                choicesDisplay=[kickStr],
                currentChoice='kick',
                delegate=self).getRootWidget()
    self._popupPartyMemberClientID = clientID
    self._popupPartyMemberIsHost = isHost
```

(This is a mod by another guy) I need the value of rst['displayString'] and check it in first sample... HELP!

I tried putting xyz = rst['displayString'] and then in file1 using

from file2 import xyz

File 1:

```
class DamnPartyWindow(PartyWindow):

def _onPartyMemberPress(self, clientID, isHost, widget):
    # if we're the host, pop up 'kick' options for all non-host members
    if bsInternal._getForegroundHostSession() is not None:
        kickStr = bs.Lstr(resource='kickText')

    else:
        # kick-votes appeared in build 14248
            if bsInternal._getConnectionToHostInfo().get('buildNumber', 0) < 14248:
                return
    kickStr = bs.Lstr(resource='kickVoteText')
    for rst in self._roster:
            cid = rst['clientID']
            xyz = rst['displayString']
            if cid == clientID:
                bs.screenMessage(rst['displayString'])
                break
    p = PopupMenuWindow(position=widget.getScreenSpaceCenter(),
                scale=2.3 if gSmallUI else 1.65 if gMedUI else 1.23,
                choices=['kick'],
                choicesDisplay=[kickStr],
                currentChoice='kick',
                delegate=self).getRootWidget()
    self._popupPartyMemberClientID = clientID
    self._popupPartyMemberIsHost = isHost
```

File 2:

```
def onPlayerRequest(self, player):

    """
    Called when a new bs.Player wants to join;
    should return True or False to accept/reject.
    """
    # importing xyz i.e the value of client
    from file2 import xyz
    if bsUtils._gStressTestResetTimer is None:
        if len(self.players) >= self._maxPlayers or xyz=="PC14567":
            # print a rejection message *only* to the client trying to joinz
            # (prevents spamming everyone else in the game)
                bs.playSound(bs.getSound('error'))
                bs.screenMessage(bs.Lstr(resource='playerLimitReachedText', subs=[('${COUNT}', bsInternal._getAccountDisplayString())]),
                            color=(0.8, 0.0, 0.0),
                            clients=[player.getInputDevice().getClientID()],
                            transient=True)
                return False
    bs.playSound(bs.getSound('dripity'))
    return True
```

But it doesnt work saying cant import xyz. 
Please help! I can give any info you guys need just help me please!

Comment: Can you add exact lines that triggered an error and an actual error message, not just `xyz` or `blah` ?
I'ts much easier to understand and help this way.
Meaning, where did you put `xyz = ....` and where tried to import ? Show that inside your code samples

Comment: @Andrew_Lvov oh yeah I am really sorry! I will do it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, first of all, your variable `xyz` is declared inside the function, so it's not available (doesn't exist) outside of it. That's why you cannot import it.

Second: sharing global variables across modules is considered a really bad practice, since it might become really complicated to track it's value changes.

As a solution, you might:

1. store `xyz` value as an attribute of a `DamnPartyWindow` class, so
   whenever you have an instance(object) of this class, you can get
   this attribute.
2. Define a common service which will store "system
   state" including value you need.
3. Looks like this is some kind of UI framework, so there should be a way to send events between components with values. So you can pass it.

Comment: @Andre_Lvov Can you please help me with creating attributes of class? I changed xyz to global variable and made a variable xyz2 outside function but inside class and used DamnPartyWindow.xyz2 but it says xyz is not defined even when its a global variable

Answer (score -1):

try:
import file1

and then use file1.xyz

Comment: Actually xyz is a variable inside function inside class so, file1.xyz will import a function or something maybe? Anyways, I tried it and it says : AttributeError : 'module' object has no attribute 'xyz'